# one Var, multiple createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, createelement

I'm creating a html structure from js.

```
var e = document;

        // HTML Tree
        $this.append(
            $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('wood-bottom'), 
            $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('jalendar-wood')
                .append(
                    $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('jalendar-pages')
                        .append(
                            $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('pages-bottom'),
                            $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('header'),
                            $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('total-bar'),
                            $(e.createElement('div')).addClass('days')
                )
            )
        );
```

and there are so many `createElement('div')` statements.

Is there a better solution for this method? 
If I define `var e = document.createElement('div')`, it doesn't work like I want.

Comment: instead of document.createElement('div') you can just use $('<div>')

Comment: Your code says you declare `e` as `document`, so why are you saying "i'm defining `var e = document.createElement('div')`"?

Comment: For building complex DOM structures, it's nicer to use some approach that's based on object structures. [JSON ML](http://jsonml.org) provides a nice approach, or you could make your own.

Comment: @koala_dev i want to createElement('div') because it's faster 5-6 times than $('div').

Comment: @ian sorry, i wanted to say 'when i'm define'

Comment: @BoraDan Based on your last comment to koala_dev, what do you **want**?  What do you mean by `is there better solution for this method?`?

Comment: @ian i mean, i want define `document.createElement('div')` method to one `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a custom function?

```
var div = function(klass){return $(document.createElement('div')).addClass(klass)};

    // HTML Tree
    $this.append(
        div('wood-bottom'), 
        div('jalendar-wood')
            .append(
                div('jalendar-pages')
                    .append(
                        div('pages-bottom'),
                        div('header'),
                        div('total-bar'),
                        div('days')
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery clone():

```
var e = document;
var $d = $(e.createElement('div'));

$this.append(
    $d.clone().addClass('wood-bottom'),
    $d.clone().addClass('jalendar-wood')
        .append(
            $d.clone().addClass('jalendar-pages')
            [...]
```

Comment: Why jQuery? Simple DOM elements have a native `clone` method as well…

Comment: That's a very good point, @Bergi!  [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) would work well too.  While at it, probably use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.attributes) to add the class, and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).  Thanks, @Bergi!